# How do I use a python 3 turtle twice

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am wondering how to use a turtle twice, 
I use the desired turtle as normal, which works but when I use the same turtle again (after resetting the turtle) every thing goes wrong.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import turtle
import time
title = turtle.Turtle()
title.hideturtle()
title.left(180)
title.forward(310)
title.right(180)
title.forward(600)
title.left(180)
title.forward(599)
title.write("WELCOME TO FUTURE WARS!", font=("Arial", 30, "normal"))
time.sleep(5)
turtle.bye()
name = input("Welcome to FUTURE WARS! What is your name?   >")
wannaplay = input( name + ", Are you ready to have a fight?   >")
if wannaplay == ("yes") or ("Yes"):
    print ("Lets Go!")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("WAIT!!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("Let me introduce myself...")
    time.sleep(2)
    print ("My name is Mineblock! I shall be your trainer!")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("Now, without any delay, (hopefully) LETS GO!")
    time.sleep(3)
else:
    print ("What are you doing here, then?")
    time.sleep(1)
    exit()

print ("Your first battle is against...")
time.sleep(2.8)
title.showturtle()
title.left(180)
title.forward(310)
title.right(180)
title.forward(600)
title.left(180)
title.forward(599)
title.write("Mineblock, Your Trainer", font=("Arial", 30, "normal"))
time.sleep(5)
turtle.bye()
```

Yes, I've googled it. No, It didn't help. Thats why I'm here!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. You need to take the time to read [mcve]. Specifically, you need to have a minimal example and the error you get in the question itself. We're not going to click through to random links, and there's no guarantee that link will stick around.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that everything goes wrong because of line 13

```
turtle.bye()
```

This shuts the turtlegraphics window and then when you want to show again the turtle in line 34 with

```
title.showturtle()
```

this raises an error cause you can't show the turtle when graphics window is shut.

To reset the turtle and reuse it you could use `turtle.reset()` instead of `turtle.bye()`